# Android WiFi Peer-to-peer (P2P): how to mock the second device using a computer?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifip2p

Suppose you only have one android device, but you would like to experiment with the Wi-Fi P2P API. Is it possible to use a computer to mock the other wifi device running whatever OS and application that is necessary to play the other part in the P2P communication? 
I know the android emulator doesn't support wifi.